# Libgdx: Skeleton stores animations and move meshes parts

Tags: java, animation, 3d, libgdx

I'm a beginner in game-dev and in 3d animation and I'd like to ask if this possible to have the following structure in libgdx for 3d model:

- one Skeleton which stores all animations set;
- mesh-parts which could be linked to Skeleton's node.

Main idea: do not store animations on each mesh and just call switch animation on main Skeleton. This will add possibility to use meshes variants for differeent model's part.

Please refer to image which represents idea (I still could not attach image):
[link on image](http://c2n.me/ivz36K)

Please, write if this idea could be implemented on libgdx or some similar solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libgdx already gives easy functionality for this.

Have a look at these classes.

- [documentation of `Model` class](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/Model.html).
- [documentation of `Node` class](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/model/Node.html).
- [documentation of `NodePart` class](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/model/NodePart.html).
- [documentation of `MeshPart` class](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/model/MeshPart.html).

Considering the fact that things are quite separated already, you can share `Animation` instances across multiple `Model`s.

Hope this helps.
Good Luck.

Comment: It seams exactly what I need. Will try to use and then say more :) Thanks!